how to prevent disabling ASO (Automatic Static Optimization) when using cookies & headers API in nextjs 13 app router rootLayout
In the Next.js app router documentation, there's a note:
"Good to know: cookies() is a Dynamic Function whose returned values cannot be known ahead of time. Using it in a layout or page will opt a route into dynamic rendering at request time."
This means that if I have to use the cookies function in the app router's root layout, I cannot use SSG (Static Site Generation) for pre-rendering.
Is there a way to use the cookies function in the app router's root layout while still enabling SSG pre-rendering at build time?


export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <ZustandProvider
          initialZustandState={{
            info: {
              ...(await getAuth({
                headers: headers(),
                cookies: cookies(), // .. want to use this APIs
              })),
            },
          }}
        >
          <QueryProvider>
                <StyledComponentsRegistry>{children}</StyledComponentsRegistry>
          </QueryProvider>
        </ZustandProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

